# #<Faraday::ConnectionFailed> Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faraday, faraday-oauth

I am receiving the message `#<Faraday::ConnectionFailed> Connection refused - connect(2)` after using checkboxes to select items in `users/edit.html.erb` and pressed save.  The items I selected are in an array called `amenities_list`. These items are booleans. After trying to save the changes I received `#<Faraday::ConnectionFailed>`.

users/edit.html.erb

```
<div class="tab-content group">

  <% amenities_list = User.amenities_list %>

  <ul>
    <% @user.boolean_array_from_amenities_integer.each_with_index do |amenity_available,index| %>
      <% if amenity_available %>
        <li class="available-amenity">
      <% else %>
        <li class="unavailable-amenity">
      <% end %>
          <%= amenities_list[index] %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

users_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.id = current_user.id
    @user.set_amenities_from_options_list!(params[:user_amenities_indicies])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Thank you for signing up! A confirmation email has been sent to your inbox"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user.id = current_user.id
    @user.set_amenities_from_options_list!(params[:user_amenities_indicies])
  end
```

user.rb

```
  def self.amenities_list
    ["Smoking Allowed",
     "Pets Allowed",
     "TV",
     "Cable TV",
     "Internet",
     "Wireless Internet",
     "Air Conditioning",
     "Heating",
     "Elevator in Building",
     "Handicap Accessible",
     "Pool",
     "Kitchen",
     "Free parking on premise",
     "Doorman",
     "Gym",
     "Hot Tub",
     "Indoor Fireplace",
     "Buzzer/Wireless Intercom",
     "Breakfast",
     "Family/Kid Friendly",
     "Suitable for Events",
     "Washer",
     "Dryer"]
  end

  def self.integer_from_options_list(options_list)
    # convert options list given by radio buttons into one-hot integer
    amenities = 0;
    if options_list
      options_list.each do |option|
        amenities += 2 ** option.to_i
      end
  end

    amenities
  end

   def self.find_with_filters(filters)
    filtered_users = User
        if filters[:amenities]
          amenities = User.integer_from_options_list(filters[:amenities])
          filtered_users = filtered_users.where("amenities & ? = ?", amenities, amenities)
        end
    end


 def set_amenities_from_options_list!(options_list)
    self.amenities = User.integer_from_options_list(options_list)
  end

    def boolean_array_from_amenities_integer
    [].tap do |amenities_list|
      User.amenities_list.length.times do |order|
        amenities_list << (self.amenities & 2 ** order > 0)
        end
      end
    end

end
```

gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.3)
      activemodel (= 4.0.3)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    arel (4.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.16)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.1.4)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    childprocess (0.5.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    debugger (1.6.6)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.3.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    elasticsearch (1.0.2)
      elasticsearch-api (= 1.0.2)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 1.0.2)
    elasticsearch-api (1.0.2)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-model (0.1.4)
      activesupport (> 3)
      elasticsearch (> 0.4)
      hashie
    elasticsearch-transport (1.0.2)
      faraday
      multi_json
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.3.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    faraday (0.9.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.3)
    figaro (0.7.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      rails (>= 3, < 5)
    geocoder (1.1.9)
    hashie (3.0.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (1.5.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.1)
    jwt (0.1.11)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_magick (3.7.0)
      subexec (~> 0.2.1)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.9.0)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.1)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    oauth (0.4.7)
    oauth2 (0.9.3)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 0.1.8)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    pg (0.17.1)
    polyglot (0.3.4)
    pry (0.9.12.6)
      coderay (~> 1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-debugger (0.2.2)
      debugger (~> 1.3)
      pry (~> 0.9.10)
    quiet_assets (1.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      activerecord (= 4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.3)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.1)
    rdoc (4.1.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.15)
    sass-rails (4.0.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.4.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      rdoc (~> 4.0, < 5.0)
    selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (< 1.0.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    simple_form (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.0, < 4.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0, < 4.1)
    slop (3.5.0)
    sorcery (0.8.5)
      bcrypt-ruby (>= 3.0)
      oauth (~> 0.4.4)
      oauth2 (>= 0.8.0, < 1.0.0)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    state_machine (1.2.0)
    subexec (0.2.3)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.2.0)
      atomic (>= 1.1.7, < 2)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.39)
    uglifier (2.5.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.1.1)
  capybara (= 2.1.0)
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  elasticsearch-model
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.2.1)
  faker
  figaro
  geocoder
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  mini_magick
  pg
  pry-debugger
  quiet_assets
  rails (= 4.0.3)
  rails_12factor
  rspec-rails (= 2.13.1)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  sdoc
  selenium-webdriver (= 2.35.1)
  simple_form
  sorcery
  state_machine
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Comment: Does it happen that you perform an underlying http request to a 3rd party service on a model callback?

Comment: No that's not the case

Comment: Can you please provide your Gemfile.lock to see which gems depend on Faraday?

Comment: I added Gemfile.lock above Aggelos

Comment: As you can see, Faraday is a dep of both elasticsearch-transport and oauth2. So, one of them causes the Faraday to perform a request. Maybe you update something in the Elasticsearch on a model callback?

Answer (score 9):

if message `#<Faraday::ConnectionFailed> Connection refused - connect(2)` is followed by 
`Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200`

then make sure elastic search service is running or not by using the command

`curl localhost:9200`

Normally, elastic search receives request at port `9200`. If not running you need to start by using command ( in Ubuntu )
`sudo service elasticsearch start`. Wait for a few seconds and try again.

Comment: I have the same issue, when I do this : $ curl localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused. Did you find a solution @Achilles77 ?